# How can I find all the vertices/faces inside a 3D sphere in script

Tags: python, scripting

**** The original post wasn't clear enough, so I've edited it ****

Is there a way for finding all the vertices/faces of objects that their coordinates are inside a given 3D sphere via script?

Comment: How do you handle with the face that intersects the boundary?

Comment: Well, it depends. For the private case I'm trying to solve, I can include also all the intersected faces

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for clarify

Computing the distance requires a square root. However, both sides of the inequality can be squared so you lose the square root and end up with basically this:
r = radius of sphere
distance = (x - x0)² + (y - y0)² + (z - z0)²

where x, y, z are the coordinates of one vertex IN the sphere
and x0,y0,z0 are the coordinates of the vertex that you are looking for.

distance = radius  -> vertex in the edge of sphere
distance < radius  -> vertex inside sphere
distance > radius  -> vertex outside sphere

[image: get inside vertices]

please use this code as example

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import random
from math import sqrt

def create_uv_sphere(name, u, v, d):

    #https://github.com/zeffii/BlenderPythonRecipes/wiki/bmesh_ops_primitives 
    # bmesh.ops.create_uvsphere also accepts a matrix keyword argument, 
    # which i've dropped from the example.
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bmesh.ops.create_uvsphere(bm, u_segments=u, v_segments=v, diameter=d)

    # create new empty mesh and fill with uvsphere
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name + "_mesh")
    bm.to_mesh(mesh)
    bm.free()

    # create object and link to scene
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name, mesh)
    bpy.context.scene.objects.link(obj)
    return obj

def calc_distance(v1, v2, radius):
    distance = sqrt( (v2.x - v1.x)**2 + (v2.y - v1.y)**2 + (v2.z - v2.z)**2)

    if distance < radius:
        inside =True
    else:
        inside =False

    return inside


#############################3

name = "my_uvsphere"
u=30
v=30
d=1
create_uv_sphere(name, u, v, d)
bpy.data.objects[name].select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects[name]
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

vs =bm.verts

if hasattr(bm.verts, "ensure_lookup_table"): 
    bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
v1 =vs[0]

number= 500
counter = 0
a=-d
b=d
while counter <=number:

    v2 = bm.verts.new((random.uniform(a, b), 
                       random.uniform(a, b), 
                       random.uniform(a, b)))

    inside  =calc_distance(v1.co, v2.co, d/2)
    if inside:
        v2.select = True

    counter+=1


bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
```

Comment: Doesn't it take only the verts and faces from obj? What I mean is finding all the vertices/faces of objects that their coordinates are inside a given 3D sphere.

Comment: @NoamPeled I update the answer

Comment: `distance = (v2 - v1).length`

Answer (score 1):

I used vector inner and outer product for the evaluation of inclusion evaluation.
Limitation:

1. Coordinate transformation to world-space is omitted.
2. Use in edit mode and set a border_obj_name by yourself.

Bug Fixed code is shown below (Nov 4, 2017)

```
border_obj_name = 'Sphere'

import bpy
import bmesh

# Setting boundary object
me = bpy.data.objects[border_obj_name].data    
bm_border = bmesh.new() 
bm_border.from_mesh(me) 

# Setting target object
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type='VERT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
me = bpy.context.edit_object.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

v_list = [v for v in bm.verts]

for fb in bm_border.faces:

    # Get the normal vector(vn) of the border face(fb)
    l = fb.loops[0]
    vo = l.vert.co
    va = l.link_loop_next.vert.co - vo
    vb = l.link_loop_prev.vert.co - vo
    vn = va.cross(vb)

    # If the inner product of v and vn is positive, the vertex is outside the face(fb).
    for vert in v_list:
        v = vert.co - vo
        if vn.dot(v) > 0:
            vert.select = False

    v_list = [v for v in v_list if v.select]

# Finalize
bm.select_flush_mode()
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
bm_border.free()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Multi mesh, object mode, version.**

---

Define your sphere via a global coordinate `sphere_co = Vector((1, 1, 1))` and radus. `sphere_radius = 1`  Script loops through selected mesh objects and selects vertices on each within the sphere.

For each mesh the sphere is converted to the mesh object's local coordinates, as well as a point on the surface of the sphere, the difference of the two being the radius vector in local coords.  If the distance from vertex (`BMVert.co`)  to local sphere coord is within the length of the local radius vector, it is selected.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector

context = bpy.context

# sphere at global coords 
sphere_co = Vector((1, 1, 1))
sphere_radius = 1
# global point on surface
radius_vec = sphere_co + Vector((0, 0, sphere_radius))
# selected meshes and their inverted world matrix
meshes = [(o.data, o.matrix_world.inverted())
        for o in context.selected_objects 
        if o.type=='MESH']

bm = bmesh.new()
for me, mwi in meshes:
    # put sphere in local coords.
    lco = mwi * sphere_co
    r = mwi * (radius_vec) - lco
    # load mesh
    bm.from_mesh(me)
    # select verts within radius
    for v in bm.verts:
        v.select = (v.co - lco).length <= r.length 
    # flush selection, update mesh
    bm.select_flush(False)   
    bm.to_mesh(me)
    bm.clear()
bm.free()
```